# Help with SSh Tunnel

Tags: ssh

I am running a Django instance locally and doing some Facebook development.

So, I set up a port on a remote machine to forward to my local machine, so that Facebook can hit the web server, and have the requests forwarded to my local machine.

Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error in my browser when I try and access the page: http://dev.thegreathive.com/

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I think the problem is on my local machine, since if I kill the SSH tunnel, the error message changes.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing a whole lot of details about your setup I'd venture the following guesses:

1. You have a firewall between your local machine and the remote host doing the tunneling that is blocking the port you are forwarding.
2. The http server on your local machine is not configured properly.
3. (Possibly) The way you have the tunnel setup on the server is not correctly returning the response from your local machine.

Hope this helps narrow down the troubleshooting!